# Which is truest source of dharma - Veda or Upnishads?

Tags: vedas, dharma, upanishads

Which is truest source of dharma - Vedas or Upnishads ?

Upnishads contains only phisophical verses while vedas have many types of verses including verses for sacrifice etc.

Vedas are revealed texts while there is doubt if Upanishads are revealed or they are written by philosphers of ancient India.

Comment: Upanishads are the integral part of Vedas, (interspersed in different portions of it) Basis of the classification ,could be the intent it holds,connected to numerous Mahavakhyas (ie if it is Brahma Vidya).For eg. Ishavasya ,is in the Samhita portion of the Shukla Yajurveda, hence recited as veda mantra , (with Rishi  , chandas , devata ) so terse , unlike the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad in the same Shukla yajur / shatapatha brahmana portion, so elaborate(with naratives/dialogue) sharing Purnamadah Purnamidham with Isavashya .

Comment: Almost all upanishads invariably contain one or more Shanti mantras.They may detail theory of causation abstractly, (unlike symbolic in Puranas),also reg. the bondage and liberation "Vedokhilo dharma moolam" Vedas are the root of dharma